# Loading google.vim indent file in Vim

Tags: c++, vim, coding-style, indentation

I am attempting to use the [google.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/google.vim) ([and on vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2636)) indent style for my c++ project, but I can't seem to load it. I installed `google.vim` using vundle and opened up a cpp file and noticed that my tabstops, shiftwidths, etc did not change. If you set global ts and sw parameters, are they not overwritten? How do you force a certain indention when editing a file in vim? I want everything in my vimrc file to be overwritten by the google.vim file when I edit a cpp file.

Running the `:filetype` command in vim reveals this information:

```
      detection:ON plugin:ON indent:ON
```

The bottom line is that I don't understand how to tell vim to use my google.vim file located under ~/.vim/vundle/google.vim/indent/google.vim. From what I have read, vim detects that filetype of your current file and uses the appropriate .vim file for syntax and indentation. So would I then have to rename my google.vim file to something like cpp.vim?

In most cases I like to use a tabstop of 3 and a shiftwidth of 3, so I set these in my .vimrc file. However, when I edit a cpp file, I want all my settings to be changed from what I have set globally to what the google.vim file sets.

Comment: I get an error message if I enter your highlighted line.  For the correct syntax, see `:help :filetype-overview`:  you want `:filetype plugin indent on`.  After adding this line to your vimrc file and installing you will need to (1) restart vim and (2) edit a C++ file.  If you need further help, please include a link to the google.vim plugin.

Comment: Sorry, the line I included was not intended to be run, I was simply showing what the output of `:filtype` was to make it clear that I have file detection on. Anyways, the link to the github google.vim project is here: https://github.com/vim-scripts/google.vim. I just want to override my current settings with the settings that in the .vim file above. For most of my files I use a tabstop and shift width of 3, but the google indent uses a tabstop and shiftwidth of 2 (of course amongst many other things.) I just don't understand how to "turn on" the google.vim indent file.. or any .vim indent file

Comment: Did you do steps (1) and (2) described in my first comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must rename the file from `google.vim` to `cpp.vim`, as indicated in [the description of the plugin on vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2636).

General explanation:

Adding `filetype plugin indent on` to your `~/.vimrc` allows Vim to detect the filetype of the files you edit (usually based on the file extention) and source filetype-specific plugins and indent scripts.

The idea is simple: you edit a file with `{{LANGUAGE}}` filetype and Vim tries to source any `ftplugin/{{LANGUAGE}}.vim` and `indent/{{LANGUAGE}}.vim` it finds in your `runtimepath`.

Because the filetype of your file is `cpp`, Vim will blissfully ignore your `google.vim` indent script so… you must rename it to `cpp.vim` for it to work.

Or you could rename all your C++ files `foobar.google` and teach Vim to recognize `*.google` files but, well… it doesn't sound right ;-)

Comment: Thank you, this answer is very helpful. Renaming google.vim to cpp.vim is what needed to be done. Furthermore, vundle did not manage the `runtimepath` correctly when installing the google.vim plugin. The path showed that it was looking in ~./vim/bundle/google.vim/after, when in fact there is no 'after' directory just an 'indent' directory. So by renaming the file and adding the correct runtimepath, I was able to use the google.vim indentation file. I guess I should let this be a lesson that Vundle doesn't always take care of everything for me when installing additional vim scripts.

Comment: It should be a lesson for everyone, I guess.